# How can i make my angular js website crawlable on search engines??

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make my angular js website crawlable by search engines.

My website is not crawled by google ??

Comment: Universaljs / Isomorphic js - https://medium.com/@mjackson/universal-javascript-4761051b7ae9#.9pbj6tsb9

Comment: thanx brother....I'll try

Answer (score 0):

There are many good materials out there to help you achieve this.

These are certain links which helped me a lot:

[Zanon tutorial on making angular spa crawlable](http://zanon.io/posts/angularjs-how-to-create-a-spa-crawlable-and-seo-friendly)

[stackoverflow answer to seo for angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805374/how-to-make-angularjs-application-crawalable)

[prerender.io for crawlable angular spa](https://prerender.io/)

[angular and SEO](https://weluse.de/blog/angularjs-seo-finally-a-piece-of-cake.html)